# Getting amount of days in decimal notation

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert the difference of two dates to days, in decimal notation, for example, at the moment I am doing this,

```
Date mostRecentDate = dates[0];
Date previousDate = dates[1];

long mostRecentTime = mostRecentDate.getTime();
long previousTime = previousDate.getTime(); 

long diffInDays = (mostRecentTime - previousTime ) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

This will always result in the whole amount of days, but I was hoping if the difference in two dates was two and a half days, I could return 2.5 or if the difference was 6 hours I could return 0.25 etc.

Thanks !

Comment: Don't use long if you want decimals.

Comment: You probably want to use doubles, then round your answer to however many decimals you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataType is the matter . You can use Double.

```
            Date[] dates = new Date[2];
        dates[1] = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-12*1000*60*60);
        dates[0] = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date mostRecentDate = dates[0];
        Date previousDate = dates[1];

        double mostRecentTime = mostRecentDate.getTime();
        double previousTime = previousDate.getTime(); 

        double diffInDays = (mostRecentTime - previousTime ) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of long you need to use double to get the difference in real number.

```
double diffInDays = (mostRecentTime - previousTime ) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

long type is integer as you divided the value whatever the answer will come it will casting to the integer and remove the decimal points